Customization point between libraries
I'm working on a bigger project which involves multiple libraries statically linked against each other.
E.g.: I have a Library A and Library B. Library B statically links against Lib A.
The problem I'm currently trying to solve is that Library A defines a template function DrawUI
template <typename T>
void DrawUI(T&) = delete; 

I would like to be able to specialize this template in Library B. I got this working by specializing the functions in a header inside B but this requires the header to be included somewhere within B. I would much rather prefer to be able to define them somewhere in a cpp instead but not sure if that's possible.
How are customization points usually implemented (e.g.: std::hash) and I have a similar thing already working with a non templated function that is marked as extern and implemented only in a cpp inside LibraryB so I was hoping I can achieve the same with this template.
Additionally I would like to be able to check at compile time if a specialization exists for a given type by calling a function within LibraryA giving it a type T to register those functions for later use if a type_trait / concept determines that a DrawUI exists for this type.

Did you see Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?

The issue you linked is not really related to my question as far as I can tell, as I want to have a customization point not just general template instantiation.

"... but this requires the header to be included somewhere within B. I would much rather prefer to be able to define them somewhere in a cpp instead but not sure if that's possible." this is what the linked q&a is about.

Ah, missed that link to the FAQ, my bad.
